# How to use a trained Neural Network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, training-data

I'm trying to understand the logic behind the use of a trained Neural Network. If I'm right : we should save the weights from the previous training, then, reload them with the new input.

For example, I have this data set :

- Input= [[0,1][1,1]]
- Output=[[1],[0]]
- Results after training = [[0.999...],[0.005...]]

And I have also saved the weights. What I don't understand is : how I should use the previous weights to make a prediction for example ? For example, I want to try a prediction with the following input [1,0]. I find a lot of resources online with Matlab or Python, but I don't find something to clearly understand what the calculations are, to do it "from scratch".

Thank you,

Comment: Can you post the code that you have so far and input data to be able to reproduce it?

Comment: I don't have write any code to use my trained network, because I don't understand how things works. I have try things like summing all the weights etc... but it doesn't work. That's why I really need to understand how to use my trained neural network

Comment: Well, how did you train it to begin with? Or are you trying to use a neural net you pulled off the Internet?

Comment: No, I build my own Neural Network with an input, an hidden layer and an output. I use sigmoid function as activation function. As I previously said : I don't understand how I could use the data from my training.

Comment: How did you get the outputs for your training set? Do the exact same thing using the trained weights to predict the output for the new sample.

Comment: The "how" is just to do a forward pass with the weights you learned, the equations for this are in any neural network book or website, you have probably seen them, just weighted sum plus activations.

Comment: So you're basically asking how to implement the `hypothesis` of `ANN`! I advise you to have the online introduction course to ANN given by *Andrew Ng*!

Comment: @yahya : I will check this course /@Matias : I understand how a Neural Network work. The problem is after the training : I dont understand wich learned weights I must use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as simple as doing your feedforward step with learned weights.

these are the steps you do in general:

1- feed forward : giving inputs to produce output labels

2-calculating the cost base on true labels of inputs which you have in a supervised problem

3-going backward in network to update your weights base on the cost

After you finished the training , you don't do step 2 and 3, you just Do the first step. going forward in network with new inputs and the **learned weights** in training process. the output is your prediction.

Comment: I understand the fact that I need to do a forward pass with the learned weights, and I know how to make a feedforward neural network with backpropagation. But I dont understand wich learned weights I need to use after my neural network is trained

Comment: there is only one weight matrix, what do you mean? there is only one set of weights that you are updating in each iteration and you need to keep it. if you understand and know how to do a feedforward as you said, do a feedforward with a new input after train with the weight matrix you have.

Comment: That what I'm trying to understand : how I must use the weight matrix ? It's not really clear for me : if I made a training with multiple inputs, then I save weights in a matrix, what is the method to use the weight matrix ? For example, should I sum them up ? Or should I iterate with them ?

Comment: @app_idea54 There is only one set of weights at any given time. Backpropagation updates those weights, which are then used on the next input. The weights used for prediction with the trained NN are the updated weights resulting from backpropagation on all training samples.